watchOS app local notification delayed if companion app is installed or unlocked
I have a watchOS and iOS app that are set to run independently from one another, I can install each separately and there is no reliance on each other with anything like WKSession.
The issue I'm having is that when I have both the iOS and watchOS app installed, if my iPhone is unlocked, the notification will be delayed about 13 seconds on the watch. If I lock my phone or uninstall the iOS app, notifications will show immediately on the watch. According to Apple, this is how notifications are currently handled when the companion app is installed.
This is my code to schedule the notification:
func scheduleNotification(secondsFromNow: Double, title: String = "", body: String = "") {
    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: secondsFromNow, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    
    // Request authorization again in case user dismissed before
    self.requestAuthorization()
    
    // Schedule the notification
    if Config.notificationsEnabled() {
        userNotificationCenter.add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error scheduling notification: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

Is there a way I can change this so the notification will display only on the device it's scheduled from without this delay? I've also tried using WatchConnectivity to schedule a notification on both devices with the same identifier as suggested here but the issue is still the same where the watch notification is delayed.
Finally I'll add that each app is completely standalone and does not rely on each other in any way. All notifications are local to the device (iOS or watchOS) that the app is running on.

You're not going to like this response, but it doesn't seem to be possible from this support page. It's possible the delay you're seeing is because it's trying to send to the phone (which is the priority) and when it can't, it's choosing the Watch.

If your iPhone is unlocked, you get notifications on your iPhone instead of your Apple Watch.


If your iPhone is locked or asleep, you get notifications on your Apple Watch, unless your Apple Watch is locked.

But there seems to be some hope with the fact that you have separate apps:

Some apps, such as the Noise app, are only on your Apple Watch. Notifications for these apps don't appear on your iPhone.

To make sure the apps are fully separate, can you go through this list and make sure the OS isn't identifying that they're related.

Different Bundle Identifiers

iOS app: com.yourcompany.youriOSApp
watchOS app: com.yourcompany.yourWatchApp


Separate the App Targets

In Xcode, make sure that the watchOS app isn't added as a target or extension of the iOS app.
The watch app should be standalone within your project, not embedded in the iOS app.


Deployment Information

In the watchOS app's Info.plist, set WKWatchOnly to YES to indicate that the app is meant to run independently of an iOS app.
Make sure the Minimum System Version is set to watchOS 6 or later, since independent watch apps are supported from watchOS 6 onwards.


Avoid Shared App Groups and Entitlements

Remove any shared app groups, keychain access groups, or entitlements that link the watchOS app to the iOS app.
This includes avoiding shared containers or any form of data sharing between the apps.


Review Notification Settings

Make sure that the notification categories and identifiers used are unique to the watch app.



The last nugget of help I can give is you could coach your user through separating the notifications. From that same support page:


Open the Apple Watch app on your iPhone, then tap the My Watch tab.
Tap Notifications.
Tap an app to see its options. To use the same notification settings on apps that appear on both your Apple Watch and iPhone, tap Mirror my iPhone. Some apps allow you to customize your notifications. Tap Custom, then choose an option:

Allow Notifications: Notifications appear in Notification Center and your Apple Watch alerts you.

Send to Notification Center: Notifications are sent directly to Notification Center without your Apple Watch alerting you.

Notifications Off: The app sends no notifications.





